# Pythonic way to check conditions

Tags: python, if-statement

I'm trying to figure out what is the most pythonic way to do statement like

```
if is not 100 or is not 101:
    do something:
```

Comment: `is not` takes two operands. Where is the left-hand operand? And you should *not* use identity to test for equality. Use `!= 100`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have an integer value and you want to test that it is not 100 and not 101, you can use an `in` membership test with a tuple:

```
if foo not in (100, 101):
```

You should **not** use identity tests (`is` and `not is`) with integers. The fact that identity tests work with small integers (between -5 and 255) is a CPython optimization detail. Identity is not the same thing as having the same value; two objects can have the same value but are not necessarily the same reference:

```
>>> value1 = 4242
>>> value2 = 4242
>>> value1 == value2
True
>>> value1 is value2
False
>>> value3 = value1  # assignment
>>> value1 == value3
True
>>> value1 is value3
True
```